# Country Code Required - Magento 2.4.3

Tags: customer, magento2.4, customer-address

On one of our websites, we have issues after they have created the account they need to add the home address and shipping address to their account. When they do so they get "Country code is required. Enter and try Again"

The language of the website is Norwegian, Magento version is 2.4.3

Has anyone had the same issue and managed to resolve this?

[image: There is no Country section on the address section]

[image: This is the error message I get when I try to save the address.]

[image]

Comment: add some more details like screen short.

Comment: Screenshot added

Comment: this is because country is required and you are not giving adding country value 
either remove the country from required or select default country from admin

Comment: That is already selected see photo above.

Comment: I can't see anywhere I can remove the country as required

Comment: select default country from admin and see if still issue then it may be due to third party theme or extension

Comment: What do you mean? The default country is set Norway.